# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-9: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, pandas

This piece of code:

```
fil = gpd.read_file(i[1],encoding='iso8859_7')
fil.to_file(out,encoding='iso8859_7')
```

While I export it without the encoding it is fine.

When I run it as it is in the sample it gives the error.

When I run it a second time like that without changing anything, it works.

Why is this happening and how to achieve the result without running a huge piece of code twice every time?